# PDO->execute() statement won't work and is syntactically correct

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't understand why this PDO statements won't save anything into the database:

```
          //guardamos en base           
          $conectar2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS); 
          $conectar2->beginTransaction();
          $agregarData = $conectar2->prepare("
              UPDATE mensajes
              SET estadoMensaje = ?, 
                  datosMensaje = ?
              WHERE mensajeID = ?;
            ");
          $agregarData->bindParam(1, $estadoMensaje);
          $agregarData->bindParam(2, $data);
          $agregarData->bindParam(3, $mensajeID);             
          $agregarData->execute();

          echo '<br>Mensaje actualizado.';
```

My error log won't say anything. Anything out of place that I could have missed?

I've tried the sql statement into mysql by hand and it works.

I've echoed the variables and they are not empty (they are all strings).

The connection does work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try testing for errors? Does execute return false? What does the `error` property tell you?

Comment: did you enable exceptions in pdo? if not, then you're simply assuming nothing ever goes wrong, and are NOT checking the return value of all those calls. PDO fails by returning boolean false, by default.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a transaction when you're only executing one statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You began a transaction but forgot to commit it.

Adding:

```
$conectar2->commit();
```

after issuing your queries will fix the problem.

You might consider removing the transaction altogether if there are no other queries being issued.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Anything out of place that I could have missed?"*

Yes.

```
$conectar2->beginTransaction();
```

This part needs to be removed.